# C - generate an input amount of random numbers with their positioning label

Tags: c

What would be the best way to generate an input amount of random numbers with their positioning labled? Like following

```
 Pos   |  Val

   0   |    2 

   1   |  924

   2   |  356
```

Currently I have the inputed amount numbers generating randomly from 0-1000 but I'm trying to figure out how to have the positioning listed from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, next to the corresponding number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int n;
  int r;
  int x;

  printf("Enter an integer");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  x = n;

  for(n=0; n<x; n++) {
    r = ( rand()%1000 ) + 1;
    printf("%d \n", r);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just change your `printf` statement to print your loop variable `n`, then maybe a tab or other spacer, then your `|` delimiter, then the random value you generated as you do now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused on how to do that, this is my first program.

Comment: `printf("%d | %d \n", n, r);`

Comment: @MichaelJohnson be aware that `rand` sucks, even if you call `srand` - I recommend using [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/download.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good practice to check whether your scanning was successful, [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled.

```
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong input!\n");
}
```

You can [format](https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output) your output according to your needs

```
printf(" Pos | Val");
for(n=0; n<x; n++)
{
    r = ( rand()%1000 ) + 1;
    printf(" %3d | %3d\n", n+1, r);
}
```

Output

```
Enter an integer: 4
  Pos |  Val
    1 |  384
    2 |  887
    3 |  778
    4 |  916
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will definitely remember that in the future.